# Selenium Python: 'Close' button on pop-up window not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Can't seem to click on a 'close' button to close a pup up window that I have opened before to scrape the data that it displays.
The button has the following html script:

```
<div class="closebutton" onclick="return hs.close(this)" title="Schließen"></div>
```

I was trying the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='closebutton']").click()
```

But I get the error:

```
Message: element not interactable
```

Anyone have a clue how to make the element interactable?

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.closebutton[title='Schließen']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='closebutton' and @title='Schließen']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.closebutton[title='Schließen']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='closebutton' and @title='Schließen']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already tried webdriver wait and Css selector. I think the issue is the pop-up window. Funny is though that I can scrape the data within the pop up window but I can't activate the close button for whatever reason.

Comment: @davvpo Did you try any of the options from the answer? What error do you see?

Comment: yes I did, I tried both with XPATH in the first place. CSS Selector has same issue. When using Webdriver.wait I get a time out error: TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: When using the normal option its: 'Message: element not interactable' for XPATH and 'Message: element not found' for CSS Selector

Comment: @davvpo From a generic perspective `<div>` tag aren't clickable, does the `<div>` have a child, maybe a `<span>`?

Comment: unfortunately not. doesn't have a child and parent is also `<div>`

Comment: But does ist help if it has an "on click" attribute, because it does